# Universal Windows App fails to launch, "AppxDeploymentFailureBlue"

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, appx, dism

I've installed my own Universal Windows App for all users on a PC, using the [DISM tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/preinstall-apps-using-dism) while being logged-in in [Audit Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-windows-to-audit-mode-or-oobe).
After doing so, I reboot into OOBE (using `sysprep` command), create a new user and try to launch this app.

The result is that nothing happens - the app doesn't launch (also checked in Task Manager).
In Windows' **Event Viewer**, I found an entry about **AppxDeploymentFailureBlue**, which appears there every time I try to launch that app - but it doesn't supply any further information about the problem or its cause. 
I tried to look for this error code online, but all I could find is some [discussions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/ms-store-apps-pre-provisioned-in-windows-10/f1e28818-665b-4242-afe7-46e9dd06c898?auth=1) about a corrupted version of the Windows Store app or Windows' built-in apps - which isn't the case here.

Further more, this app has a **StartupTask**, and its failure to properly launch seems to be blocking other apps from registering themselves in the Startup tasks/apps list (if the app isn't installed, then they are registered successfully).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple in hindsight, but not easy to track down:

Turns out one of the app's dependencies wasn't installed. Seems like installing a Universal App with DISM in Audit Mode (as opposed to when installing as regular local user) doesn't give any indication about missing pre-requisites.

In order to figure out which dependency was missing, I went over the App's `AppxManifest.xml`'s `<Dependencies>` section. In order to check which are installed and which aren't, I used the following command: `Dism /Online /Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages`.

After installing the missing package (in my case, that was **Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop**), everything went back to normal.